# Play Framework : How to set cookie with custom path

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to set a cookie on my play application(v1.2.4) and want the path to be "/". But since my application has http.path=/portal, the cookie path is always "/portal". I tried looking for a way to specify defaultCookiePath but could not find anything. It looks like cookie path is always derived from the http.path value.

Comment: why are you looking to change that

Comment: I need the cookie to be accessable by another application running on the same domain.

Comment: Have you looked into Play.ctxPath

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the location for the cookie via Play.ctxPath. In bootstrap.java, you can set up the path:

```
Play.ctxPath="/";
```